# BadDataError when converting .DBF to .csv

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, dbf

I am trying to convert a .DBF file to .csv using Python3. I am trying using the dbf library (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf)

```
import dbf 

def dbf_to_csv(dbf_file_name, csv_file_name):
    dbf_file = dbf.Table(dbf_file_name, ignore_memos=True)
    dbf_file.open() 
    dbf.export(dbf_file, filename = csv_file_name, format='csv', header=True)
```

The DBF file I am using can be opened in Excel and appears to be fine. However, when I run the above method I get an error on the dbf.export line above:

```
dbf.ver_33.BadDataError: record data is not the correct length (should be 1442, not 1438)
```

The dbf file opens fine in Excel, however, I need to automate this conversion. What should I be doing differently to get this method to create a pdf from a .DBF file?

Comment: I'd be happy to take a look at the file if you are able to send it.  You can find my email address in the `dbf` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is opening correctly in Excel, then I suggest you use Excel to do the conversion for you to `csv` format as follows:

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"input.dbf")
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.SaveAs(r"output.csv", FileFormat=6, ConflictResolution=2)
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Do not forget to add full paths to the required files. Note, `FileFormat=6` tells Excel to save the file in `CSV` format.

To export the workbook as a PDF, you could use:

```
wb.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, r"output.pdf")
```

If you do not already have `win32com` installed you should be able to use the following:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

This solution is suitable for Windows installations only.

Comment: That library does not install for me. I get this error:         print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
                               ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
Does this only install on Windows machines? I really need something cross platform.

Comment: Unfortunately, `win32` is Windows only, sorry.

Comment: I got this on a windows machine and am getting the following error, any ideas?:   File ".\shared\utilities.py", line 58, in dbf_to_csv
    wb.SaveAs(csv_file_name, FileFormat=6, ConflictResolution=2)
  File "C:\cygwin\tmp\gen_py\3.5\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x8\_Workbook.py", line 259, in SaveAs
    , Local)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'SaveAs method of Workbook class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: Not seen that before, I assume Excel is installed ok? It might be due to the file location you are trying to write to. Make sure you have write permission for that folder. I recommend putting a full path to both input and output files, e.g. try the desktop. If you Google the error `SaveAs method of Workbook class failed` there are quite a few suggestions.

Comment: I updated the file paths to include double backslashes and it ran fine. I really wish the dbf package would work so it would be cross-platform but this is good enough for now. Thanks!